# Traefik v2 reverse proxy to a local server outside Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, webserver, traefik

I have a simple server written in Python that listens on port 8000 inside a private network (HTTP communication). There is now a requirement to switch to HTTPS communications and  every client that sends a request to the server should get authenticated with his own cert/key pair.

I have decided to use Traefik v2 for this job. [Please see the block diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOBnz.png)

Traefik runs as a Docker image on a host that has IP 192.168.56.101. First I wanted to simply forward a HTTP request from a client to Traefik and then to the Python server running outside Docker on port 8000. I would add the TLS functionality when the forwarding is running properly.

However, I can not figure out how to configure Traefik to reverse proxy from i.e. `192.168.56.101/notify?wrn=1` to the Python server `127.0.0.1:8000/notify?wrn=1`.

When I try to send the above mentioned request to the server (`curl "192.168.56.101/notify?wrn=1"`) I get "*Bad Gateway*" as an answer. What am I missing here? This is the first time that I am in contact with Docker and reverse proxy/Traefik. I believe it has something to do with ports but I can not figure it out.

Here is my Traefik configuration:

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    container_name: "traefik"
    hostname: "traefik"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro"
```

- traefik.yml

```
## STATIC CONFIGURATION
log:
  level: INFO

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"

providers:
  docker:
    watch: true
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  file:
    filename: "traefik.yml"


## DYNAMIC CONFIGURATION
http:
  routers:
    to-local-ip:
      rule: "Host(`192.168.56.101`)"
      service: to-local-ip
      entryPoints:
        - web

  services:
    to-local-ip:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 127.0.0.1 will resolve to the traefik container and not to the docker host. You need to provide a private IP of the node and it needs to be accessible form the traefik container.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! I have managed to solve my problem with `network_mode: host` in my _docker-compose.yml_ file.

Comment: For anyone who is curious, `network_mode: host` should be under the named service section in the docker-compose.yml file for the reverse proxy listener container (same level as environment/ports/volumes). In my case I didn't need any top-level `network` description.

Answer (score 0):

There is some workaround to make proxy to localhost:
change 127.0.0.1 to IP of docker0 interface
It should be 172.17.0.1

and then try to listen your python server on all interfaces (0.0.0.0)
if you use simple python http server nothing change... on default it listen on all interfaces